# Fragment not showing until the screen is rotated

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

So i am facing this weird problem where the fragment A is replaced with another fragment B but after replacing fragment A the screen becomes blank  and only after I rotate the screen or the app comes from background then the fragment B shows up. I have added logs in fragment B oncreateView and they are getting called but the fragment is not shown. I cant seem to figure out what could be the issue here

Here is the code for fragment replacment

```
        GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Main) {
              val testfragment= TestFragment()     
              supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().
              replace(R.id.fragmelayout,testfragment, "test").commit() 
                            }
```

Edit A:

So i figured what was causing the issue but still confused cause it shouldnt be happening 
There is a recyclerview in the view that is in the fragment A and as soon as I comment it out the transition is as expected, fragment A can be replaced with fragment B and fragment B shows first time

Here is the recyclerview in the xml

```
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/personal_bluetooth_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:orientation="horizontal" />
```

And here is the recyclerview getting populated in

```
bluetoothDeviceRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.personal_bluetooth_recyclerview)
    bluetoothDeviceRecyclerViewAdapter = PersonalBluetoothRecyclerViewAdapter(mListLeDevice, isDebugMode, this)
    bluetoothDeviceRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
    bluetoothDeviceRecyclerView.adapter = bluetoothDeviceRecyclerViewAdapter
    bluetoothDeviceRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    bluetoothDeviceRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20)
    bluetoothDeviceRecyclerView.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
    bluetoothDeviceRecyclerView.drawingCacheQuality = View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH
```

Comment: The fragment transaction looks ok to me. Is it possible that this code is running on a background thread?

Comment: @E.M. Thats what i thought so i added it on main thread but still same behaviour and even if it was on background thread , it shouldnt show at all , but it shows after the fragment state is changed (app resuming from background or screen rotated )

Comment: @chossen-addict where are you replacing your fragment A with fragment B? Is it inside fragment A or in activity?

Comment: @AidaIsay This was from inside the activity

Comment: @chossen-addict, I feel like more context is required to be helpful. Have you created a minimal working example that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: @E.M.please check the edit